# Object must implement IConvertible MySQL C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Using `MySqlDataReader`, I try to read a primary key which is int(11). `int id=reader.GetInt32(0);` gives the error "Object must implement IConvertible". What is the reason? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please show the stack trace you're getting. I suspect you'll want a different type though, as an `Int32` can't handle 11 digits...

Comment: whether `reader.GetInt32()` is capable of handling `DbNull`? i think that is the reason for exception

Comment: It occurs because of some missing statements. Anyway thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

`reader.GetInt32(0)` will accept the argument as `columnIndex` this will throw exceptions as like the following :credits to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablereader.getint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)
[image] 
you can trace out the error using :

```
while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.IsDBNull(2))
        {
            Console.Write("<NULL>");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Console.Write(reader.GetInt32(2));
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException)
            {
                Console.Write("Invalid data type.");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: It is an InvalidCastException error. I tried with long data type, but I got the error again